# SolrCloud Exception writing document id to the index; possible analysis error

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have a problem with my solrcloud 6.2.1, bad request after some docs indexed.

which I have done :

- **HardCommit**
- Every <1min commit=false  (400-600 Docs)
- Every 10mins commit=true with command `curl http://host:8983/solr/mycollection/update?commit=true`
- Change all my dynamic field to static (40+ field, all needed)
- Change some field properties just indexed but not to stored
- Increase JVM
- Using load balancer

Its fine after restart all solr service. But after 500K-900K docs indexed or no longer than 1 day, it will be error, and that's always gives same Error. This makes me confused, i haven't been able to solve this for a month. Anyone here has a solution ?

here is error message `https://pastebin.com/mnZxYRWY`

```
RequestHandlerBase
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception writing document id 999213794621579264 to the index; possible analysis error.
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception writing document id 999213794621579264 to the index; possible analysis error.
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:178)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:335)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:939)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1094)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:720)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader$1.update(JavabinLoader.java:97)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readOuterMostDocIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:179)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:274)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readNamedList(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:121)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:239)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:157)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:107)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2089)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:652)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:459)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:257)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexWriter is closed
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.ensureOpen(IndexWriter.java:740)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.ensureOpen(IndexWriter.java:754)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1558)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:279)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:211)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:166)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.LZ4.decompress(LZ4.java:132)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressionMode$4.decompress(CompressionMode.java:138)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader$BlockState.doReset(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:488)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader$BlockState.reset(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:394)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader.document(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:573)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsWriter.merge(CompressingStoredFieldsWriter.java:607)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeFields(SegmentMerger.java:200)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:89)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4312)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3889)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:588)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:626)
```

Comment: How about using commitWithin instead of explicit commits? Possibly an issue where multiple threads are trying to use the same writer, but its being closed while the write is being attempted.

Comment: could you please put your error message in the text of the question, please

Comment: im try commitwithin 10seconds, it's not changed at all

Comment: okay, could you show the code, how you're doing the indexing?

Comment: ah my bad, thanks all. I used a special 1 min for commit = true, and no one made commit=false at the time. And use commitWithin for a time limit of no more than 50 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Since it mentioned a possible analysis chain error, you may use the analysis interface via the Solr admin page to identify the indexing problem. Get the documents that failing the indexing, then try the values in the index box of the corresponding fields. You will find which value caused an index error, check your analysis chain in the schema file.